# MSSQL(SQL SERVER 16) Update range of rows based on non int values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is it possible to UPDATE a range of rows based on text?[image: The table on the left is the data that has been imported. Table on the right is the end goal.]
[EDIT]:The table on the left is the data that has been imported. Table on the right is the end goal.

Column B, values ISA-IEA is used to designate the beginning and end of an EDI order(simplified). Real data is variable in row count, so sometimes there may be 5 rows, sometimes 45 rows. So I cannot simply select 5 ROWs then move on to the next.
Thanks for any direction.

EDIT for CLARIFICATION: I'm going to leave the original example, and include this additional example. Again table on the left is current data and what I'm trying to accomplish is the right. thanks! [image]

Comment: but...what do you want to do?

Comment: no column express the order nor group you show in the first picture. Also, column D last row shouldn't be value 51?

Comment: How exactly would you determine what a sequence is? There's no other column to relate things togethe rin any way, shape or form

Comment: A table is defined as a set of *unordered* rows.  If you have imported from a file that has the rows saved in a specific order, then you will need to import the data with the value from Column A.  If you've already imported the data, you've lost that order because an SQL table is not required to store rows in a specific order.  In C# terms, it's like you're trying to create an ordered hashtable from a plain hashtable.  It's not going to work.  I'd recommend importing the data with a script to populate Column A.

Comment: Try to import the rows into a table with an identity column (given that you are exporting in the shown order). Then you can use the Id to create a "block" number for column A, e. b. by updating the ISA columns by using the row_number() function. Then update all the other rows <> ISA with the same Id until the next ISA. Something like that.

Comment: @ Lamak - I would like to identify rows beginning with ISA through IEA with the DocumentID which is located in the 4th column of ISA.

@ Horaciux - yes, I just added a couple more orders for example and forgot to update the IEA value, thanks.
@ SchmitzIT - A sequence begins with ISA and ends with IEA.
@ BaconBits - thanks for the definition, I did not import the data with a value in column A(I added the column).

Comment: @Shavelieva In your question, you mention there can be 5-45 rows per sequence. Would they always be in a specific order? If so, then you have to store that specific order somewhere. I.e. ISA = 1, BFR = 2, etc. You can then use that order to help order things properly. However, whereever you have FST, there's multiple entries. What determines the order for those, exactly?

Comment: @SchmitzIT - yes, ISA will always instantiate the beginning of an EDI order. I did briefly try that, but wasn't sure where to move from there.
UPDATE #testtable2
SET [Column A] = CASE
     WHEN [Column B] = 'ISA' THEN 1
     WHEN [Column B] = 'IEA' THEN 2
END

In regards to FST rows, that contains the order quantity and date, sort order isn't relevant to those rows except that they exist between ISA & IEA. Could it make sense to ID ISA=1, BFR=2, FST=2, & IEA=3?

Comment: If I were you, i'd create a table for it. Much easier than adding a lot of CASE statements in the long run. If all you need, though, is ISA = 1, anything else is meh, and IEA is always last, CASE might work. Something like `CASE [Column B] WHEN 'ISA' THEN 1, WHEN 'IEA' THEN 99 ELSE 50 END`. That leaves you with plenty of room inbetween in case the business logic would change. I still think a table would be easier to maintain, though. You then just join to it, and at the same time can also sort by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to catch the top most (by E column desc) row where B equals ISA.
Here is how:

```
drop table if exists dbo.Test;

create table dbo.Test (
    A int
    , B varchar(100)
    , C varchar(100)
    , D varchar(100)
    , E int
);

insert into dbo.Test (A, B, C, D, E)
values (null, 'ISA', '170607', 48, 1)
    , (null, 'BFR', '170607', 1, 2)
    , (null, 'FST', '170607', 1, 3)
    , (null, 'IEA', '170607', 48, 4)
    , (null, 'ISA', '170607', 49, 5)
    , (null, 'BFR', '170607', 1, 6)
    , (null, 'FST', '170607', 1, 8)
    , (null, 'FST', '170607', 1, 9)
    , (null, 'IEA', '170607', 49, 10);

update tu
set
    A = tc.D
from dbo.Test t
    outer apply (
            select
            top (1)
                tt.D
            from dbo.Test tt
            where tt.B = 'ISA'
                and tt.E <= t.E
            order by tt.E desc
    ) tc
    inner join dbo.Test tu on t.E = tu.E

select
*
from dbo.Test t
```

Comment: ok, seeing this helped me understand, thanks for taking the time.